# Angular - caching data with base64 images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, local-storage, ng-storage

Suppose I have an app that lists restaurants in a given city. As you can imagine there may be quite a few listings making up a sizable amount of data, and thats without any images.

Now suppose I want to give users quick access to this data by caching it. The way I implement my cache is by simply storing the data using `ngStorage`, checking if it exists.. if it does, I pull my scope from `$localStorage`, if not, I get the data from the DB and set the `$localStorage`.

```
$scope.Restaurants = {};
if(Object.keys($localStorage.restaurants).length===0){ 

    $http.get('www.mydata.internet/RESTaurants').then(function(res){ // pardon the pun

        $localStorage.restaurants = res.data.restaurants;
        $scope.Restaurants = res.data.restaurants;

    });

} else $scope.Restaurants = $localStorage.restaurants;
```

This works fine until I store images in my DB as base64.

All of a sudden the amount of data grows significantly, ngStorage meets a limit & breaks. Also, pulling down tons of images and shoving them in local storage doesnt exactly scale well.

But I would still like to cache this data to avoid making DB calls every time its needed.

Is there some way to cache a large amount of data like this?

Comment: implement the linear loading of data as the user scrolls down thru the listing

Comment: See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) and [AngularJS $cacheFactory Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory).

Comment: If you are able to extend your server side api, why not call the image(s) via a separate request. like `/RESTaurant/2051/image/store.jpg`, with `Cache-Control`? This way the image can load from the browser cache (304 not modified) on subsequent calls... mostly..

Comment: Searching, this is a good idea that I started to implement but ran into some asynchronicity issues, which I'll have to resolve. but ultimately I think this will be the solution until I develop a more robust scheme to serve the data

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a lot to consider in this scenario.

I would first consider how you're loading the data for your application to determine if you *really* need to cache this much data. How many server calls are you making to load the data? Are you making one request to get all the data up front (i.e. all the restaurants for a selected city) or do you load some of it a time (i.e. a server request for 5 restaurants at a time)?

Also, are you eagerly loading or lazily loading the data (or a combination of both)? Do you ask for some data up front initially and then load more detailed data in the background?

After answering the previous questions, determine if a need for a large cache is still there or if you can rework how the data is loaded to avoid caching or stick to a smaller caching mechanism you have already mentioned such as local storage.

If you are still in need for a larger caching mechanism, I would consider trying to cache data server side so you're not constantly querying your database(s). If you must cache large amounts of data on the client (browser) including images, I would consider looking into storing images as blobs in something like [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Comment: thank you for your reply! I am loading all the data when the application initializes. if its the first time a user is accessing, I initialize the cache from DB (which is a bit slow.. up to 5 sec..but a one-time thing) on subsequent hard reloads, Im checking for cache and sometimes updating with new data lazily. Although the initial load is eager. I am already storing my images as blobs but server-side. should I look into adding a client side DB (mongo?) for large cache?

Comment: I would highly consider trying to avoid loading all the data when the application initializes as this sounds like your performance bottleneck. I'm sure there's a way you could rework your UI so the user asks for smaller amounts of data at once. Again, if you _really_ can't rework how the data is requested, I would look into something like IndexedDB on the client-side. As for MongoDB -- this is a server-side NoSQL database which won't give you much of performance boost unless your data models are nested objects that can benefit from being de-normalized.